# Simple form wrap html and methods around radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm probably being dim here, so sorry for a potentially trivial question. I've a form which I'd like to improve. It's a simple set of radio buttons which I'd like to jazz up a bit. Basically turn it into table rows and add extra content, so for each element of my collection there is a description method which returns some text, which I'd like as the next column.

The basic is as simple as:

```
<%= simple_form_for @subscription do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :subscription_level_id, as: :radio_buttons, collection: Application.application.active_admin_subscription_levels %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Get Quote' %>
<% end %>
```

the output I'd like is:

```
<tr><td>[Radio button] name</td><td><%= ??.description %></td></tr>
<tr><td>[Radio button] name</td><td><%= ??.description %></td></tr>
etc..
```

How best to achieve that?

Comment: According the your format I would suggest, 1: Use `radio _button` 2: loop the collection to generate radio button according to the above format. 
I will add the answer if you still face the problem in generating the strucure.

Comment: OK, I can certainly do that.. let me give it a whirl. I was thinking there might be a better way than building my own - but looking at the api, it seems quite clean.

Comment: Yes! @Kh Ammad, That works just fine: `<table width="100%">
    <% Application.application.active_admin_subscription_levels.each do |level| %>
      <tr>
        <td width="20%"><%= f.radio_button(:subscription_level_id, level.id) %> <%= level.name %></td>
        <td><%= level.description %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>`

Comment: Exactly. In controller if you can assign this `Application.application.active_admin_subscription_levels` to any instance variable i.e `@subscriptions` and use this in the view. it really clean your code. It is not recomended to make queries in the views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer provided by Kh Ammad in the comment, the resulting code gives the equivalent post values, and achieves the result. Many thanks!

```
<table width="100%"> 
  <% Application.application.active_admin_subscription_levels.each do |level| %> 
    <tr>
      <td width="20%">
         <%= f.radio_button(:subscription_level_id, level.id) %> <%= level.name %>
      </td> 
      <td>
        <%= level.description %>
      </td> 
    </tr> 
  <% end %> 
</table>
```